# Numpy array python: conversion in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a simple double bracket numpy array

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

ar = np.array([[1,2,3,4]])
```

I am trying to convert it into a pandas series, but because of double brackets I am getting the below error.

```
pd.Series(ar)
```

....

```
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

how to achieve this in python

Answer (score 4):

Using [`np.squeeze`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html):

```
ar = np.array([[1,2,3,4]])
s = pd.Series(np.squeeze(ar))
s
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do it:

```
pd.Series(ar[0])
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Its pure array method, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) or [`numpy.flatten`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html):

```
s = pd.Series(ar.ravel())
#alternetive
#s = pd.Series(ar.flatten())
print (s)
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
dtype: int32
```